# How to create a Report view to return pdf report for requested samples in Django rest Framework views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I need to create a Report view to return pdf report for requested samples (just the list of samples as a content). How do I go about doing it

**Below are my models**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    created_at =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)   

class Embryo(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
     analysis_result = models.Charfield(max_length=10)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Here's a sample:**

```
[
{
"name": "embryo_1",
"analysis_results": "46,XX"
},
{
"name": "embryo_2",
"analysis_results": "47,XY,+21"
},
{
"name": "embryo_3",
"analysis_results": "46,XY"
},
]
```

Comment: There are several libraries. This is the one I use https://www.html2pdf.fr/es/home

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto thanks I did eventually figure this out